# List comprehension if statement based on previous element

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, list-comprehension

I have the following

```
U = np.array([1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.])
c = iter(range(2, len(U)))
result = [float(next(c)) if x == 1 else x for x in U]
```

This gives
`[2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 0.0`]
However I want that when the element on the left is label a number that the one the 'loop' is on becomes the same label.

So this
`[2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 0.0`]

A for-loop that describes this is the following:

```
U=np.array([1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.])
l=2
for i in range(len(U[:])):  
    i+1                       #for simplicity I skipped the first one
    if U[i]==1:
        if U[i-1]!=0:
            U[i]=U[i-1]
        else:
            U[i]=l
            l+=1
```

This returns

```
array([1., 0., 0., 2., 2., 0., 3., 3., 3.])
```

Comment: I don’t understand what you are trying to do. Can you write it as a normal `for` loop?

Comment: you cannot use the generated content in a list comp to decide on the next element thats generated. use a normal for loop.

Comment: The speed benefit of list comprehensions is minor.   If the loop is too complicated don't try to force it.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what do do with the `result` output:

- store 0 if input is 0
- store the first value of c, if the input is 1
- advance c if the input transitions from 1 to 0 (falling edge)

As in python we cannot inspect the first element of an iterator, so we need to make it into a list or any other datastructure that supports that. To decide if we have a fallen edge, we need to have access to two consecutive element in one iteration.

Here is the solution without list comprehension. Note that you transorm everything into a list comprehension as long as you do not store intermediate values.

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools

U = np.array([1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.])
c = list(range(1, len(U)))

R = []
for U_curr, U_next in itertools.zip_longest(U, U[1:], fillvalue=0):
    if U_curr == 0:
        res.append(0)
    else:
        if U_curr == 1 and U_next == 0:
            val = c.pop(0)
        else:
            val = c[0]
        R.append(float(val))
```

Here is the above in a list comprehension:

```py
U = np.array([1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.])
c = list(range(1, len(U)))

R = [float(c.pop(0) if U_curr == 1 and U_next == 0 else c[0]) if U_curr != 0 else 0
     for U_curr, U_next in itertools.zip_longest(U, U[1:], fillvalue=0)]
```

Both will output

```py
[1.0, 0, 0, 2.0, 2.0, 0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```